# Purging unused foreign keys

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

Two tables A and B, A records contain a reference to a B record.

I have some records in B which aren't being used by A.

Just after an SQL statement to remove them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM B
WHERE bid NOT IN
      ( SELECT A.bid
        FROM A
      )
```